# Scifi-Fantasy not on the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

From what I can tell, our site is not available for searching through the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Why is this and what can we do to help get it there?

Comment: my bad ... will add it next time around

Comment: @SamSaffron: I don't think it's there, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/queries

Most recent: 2012 Feb 2

Comment: Case closed. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly only sites out of beta are included, and the export only happens monthly (for data explorer – downloadable export is less frequent).

With this site newly out of beta, there may not have been an export *yet*.

Comment: But this site came out of beta on Dec 13, and the data explorer was updated on Dec 21–22.

Answer (score -6):

As I think, Stack Exchange doesn't assume this QnA site as useful real-world knowledge resource.
Forums were introduced because books & knowledge websites present ideal situation. But, in real world, we face **real-world problems**. The advantage of a QnA site over a forum is that finding answer for a particular question is fast. Nobody needs to dig too deep inside a thread. Build on this concept, Stack Overflow became successful in past. All other QnA sites in Stack Exchange network are build around this concept: To help professionals (or, anyone) find solution of **real-world problems** quickly.
Science Fiction & Fantasy is meant only for virtual world based entertainment. So, Stack Exchange has excluded it from Data Explorer.